# Visual Studio backwards step navigation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to navigate backwards when you use a command that causes the cursor to jump to a different section of the same document, or switch documents all together?

An example:  Hitting F12 causes cursor to jump to selection definition, the key combination I am looking for would return to the specific reference of the definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your keyboard scheme, but on mine <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> brings me back to the previous edit point.

To find the current key assigned to this functionality go to the menu `Tools - Options` 
Then search `Environment - Keyboard` and look for `View.NavigateBackward` command

Answer (score 0):

Please, pay attention to `View.PopBrowseContext` command. It always returns you to the very place where you have pressed F12. So it is opposite to `Jump to definition`.
It doesn't take in account any movements or edits you did after you have pressed F12. It just brings you back.

It's pity that in VS2015 they decided to get rid of this command.